# Actualizar letras mayusculas/minusculas de los campos, todos igual primera letra de cada palabra mayuscula

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo 2 campos distintos donde uno almaceno un solo nombre ejemplo "Sean Michaels" y otro donde almaceno varios separados con una coma detrás de la coma puede ir tanto el nombre como un espacio ejemplo "Sean Michaels, Mr. Marcus, Steve Holmes"
Algunos nombres pueden tener caracteres especiales como tildes o '.

El problema que algunos tengo guardado el texto como ejemplo:

Sean Michaels

Sean michaels

sean michaels

SEAN MICHAELS

y necesitaría que todos quedaran de esta forma "Sean Michaels" (primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula) y lo mismo en el otro campo que incluye varios separados con ,

Me gustaría si es posible desde una consulta SQL metida por el phpmyadmin que actualizara todos esos campos especificados.

Comment: Si en un campo estás almacenando el nombre, no deberías repetirlo en otro. Por qué separas nombres por coma? No deberías tener en otra tabla la relación entre los distintos nombres? (se que no respondo tu pregunta, pero tal vez tenés un problema de base que solucionar).

Comment: ¿Qué pasa con nombres con doble mayúscula como MacDonald o O'Tool?

Comment: Cierto no había pensado en los nombres con doble mayúscula.
Un problema mas.

Answer (score 0):

Para este tipo de problemas, las tablas de números (o `tally tables` en inglés) son una gran herramienta. Ellas nos ayudan a recorrer la cadena sin necesidad de utilizar bucles explícitos y poder utilizar funciones tipo tabla en línea que no afectan el rendimiento de las consultas. En este ejemplo, creo una tabla de números al vuelo que evita la lectura al disco y la genera completamente en memoria. La limito al número de caracteres de la cadena y luego valido los caracteres comparándolos con el anterior.

```
DECLARE @String varchar(8000) = 'SEAN MICHAELS';

WITH 
E(n) AS( --10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --10x10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( --100x100 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para varchar(8000))
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@String)) --Limitamos las filas
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n --Generamos los números
    FROM E4
)
SELECT ( SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING( @String, n-1, 1) LIKE '[A-Za-z]' --Si el caracter anterior es una letra
            THEN LOWER( SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1)) --ponemos el caracter en minúscula
            ELSE UPPER( SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1)) END --si no, lo ponemos en mayúscula
        FROM cteTally
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(8000)'); --FOR XML PATH concatena el resultado y lo convertimos en texto
```

Esta consulta, la podemos convertir fácilmente en una función tipo tabla.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ConvertirTipoTitulo
(
    @String varchar(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE  --Regresa una tabla
WITH SCHEMABINDING --Le ayuda a SQL Server a identificar que no depende de ningún objeto
AS 
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS( --10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --10x10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( --100x100 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para varchar(8000))
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@String)) --Limitamos las filas
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n --Generamos los números
    FROM E4
)
SELECT ( SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING( @String, n-1, 1) LIKE '[A-Za-z]' --Si el caracter anterior es una letra
            THEN LOWER( SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1)) --ponemos el caracter en minúscula
            ELSE UPPER( SUBSTRING( @String, n, 1)) END --si no, lo ponemos en mayúscula
        FROM cteTally
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(8000)') AS Cadena; --FOR XML PATH concatena el resultado y lo convertimos en texto
```

Ahora, esta función solo la tenemos que llamar usando APPLY.

```
SELECT tt.Cadena, t.*
FROM MiTabla t
CROSS APPLY dbo.ConvertirTipoTitulo( LaColumnaAConvertir) tt;
```

Comment: muchas gracias.
detrás de las comillas este si pondría la letra en mayúscula?

Comment: Analízalo, pruébalo, compréndelo y podrás saber. Es importante no usar código de internet sin comprenderlo.